# AR(1) Process first term

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series

I'm trying to generate a very simple AR(1) Process with *Mathematica* using the `ARProcess[]` function. The process must have the following format:

$Y_t = \alpha + \beta Y_{t−1} + ϵ_t$

However, after reading the *Mathematica* [help file](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ARProcess.html) and some [posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ARProcess) about `ARProcess[]` at MMA.SE, I couldn't find a way to correctly generate the process. I seems that the `ARProcess[]` function cannot deal with the $\alpha$ term of the process.

For instance, consider the process described below:

$Y_t = 10 + .6Y_{t−1} + ϵ_t$  , where $ϵ_t$ is Normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $4$ (i.e., $ϵ_t \sim N(0,2)$).

If I use `ARProcess[{.6},4]` I get

```
Mean[ARProcess[{.6}, 4][t]]
Variance[ARProcess[{.6}, 4][t]]
```

> Out[1]= 0
>
> Out[2]= 6.25

which are consistent with an AR(1) process of the form $Y_t = 0 + .6Y_{t−1} + ϵ_t$

I would like to be able to, though the `ARProcess[]` function, calculate the **mean** and the **variance** of the process $Y_t = 10 + .6Y_{t−1} + ϵ_t$ in order to get a **Mean** of $25$ and a **Variance** of $6.25$.

Is there any way to achieve this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Fred it does't work... what you've suggested works like an AR(2) Process of the form $Y_t=0+10 Y_{t-1} + .6 Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$, which is not stationary and, as such, the mean cannot be computed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm deleting the comment and will delete this one later.

Comment: Don't worry @Fred... I think it's somehow a bug in *Mathematica*...

Comment: One other thought, is there a way to get the $10$ into the function?

Comment: Ahah... That's *exactly* what I'm trying to figure out! I think it's not possible and, as such, it could be a bug in *Mathematica*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `ARProcess` requires that the input term $e_t$ be a zero mean white noise with a specified variance. What you are trying to do is to have your input term be $10+e_t$ which is clearly not zero mean.

What you can do is to change variables. In your case, if you define a new process $z_t=y_t - 25$ then it will be the same as the $y_t$ process. To see this, consider the "new" problem:

$z_t = 0.6 z_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

Substituting the definition of $z_t$ gives

$(y_t -25) = 0.6 (y_{t-1}-25) + \epsilon_t$

which, when rearranged is

$y_t = 0.6 y_{t-1} + 10 + \epsilon_t$.

which is the same as your orignal problem. This kind of thing is called "shifting the process". So the way to handle this is to work in the $z$ variable, get whatever answer you are looking for, and then at the very end shift back to $y$ via $y_t=z_t+25$.

Accordingly, you can use

```
varz = Variance[ARProcess[{.6}, 4][t]]
```

to get the variance of the $z$ process and

```
meanz = Mean[ARProcess[{.6}, 4][t]]
```

to get the mean of the $z$ process. Your original $y$ process has the same variance `varz`, and mean `25+meanz`.

Comment: I explicitly wrote that $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,2)$, i.e., $\epsilon_t$ has $0$-mean (and not 10!). The **AR(1) process** has mean equal to $25$ and **can** accept an $\alpha$-term (in this case, 10) per definition. The problem is exactly that: the `ARProcess[]` doesn't accept this $\alpha$-term. BTW, the $\alpha$-term has no influence on the $\epsilon_t$ mean...

Comment: The above shows you how to use the Mathematica command `ARProcess` to act like an AR(1) process with nonzero mean. You cannot enter (as far as I know) a nonzero-mean input into `ARProcess`. But the point is: you don't need to. You can do *the same thing* by redefining your terms -- as shown above. There is no bug.

Comment: So what is the point in using `Mean[ARProcess[]]` if the result will be always zero? I mean, if the `ARProcess[]` function cannot deal with an $\alpha$-term, its much better to develop an AR function by yourself instead of using *Mathematica*'s `ARProcess[]`...

Comment: You said "You cannot enter (as far as I know) a nonzero-mean input into ARProcess"... so, this must be a bug, don't you think? Imagine two **different** processes: 1) $Y_t=10+Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$ and 2) $Y_t=0+Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$; they are clearly different but if you try to estimate both processes with `EstimatedProcess[data, ARProcess[1]]` you will get **exactly** the same result, which is not consistent with one of the processes... so I'm getting wrong results if I use *Mathematica*-`ARProcess`...

Comment: I think it just doesn't work the way you expect. It seems to me that the most common procedure in *any* data analysis is to take out the mean. That's all you need to do in the case you cite and then it will give you sensible answers. I agree that it would be nicer if it allowed specification of the mean, but the documentation is pretty clear that it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think the documentation is clear about removing the mean... the shift operator **E** in the `Details` uses 1 instead of an $a_0$-term. In the `Applications` part there is a single example (daily exchange rates of the euro to the dollar) where it removes the mean and then add it back for forecasting... I don't think an example is *clear* enough for defining the function...